# "set_memory_rw" UNDEFINED when compiling kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am having trouble compiling and installing a kernel module, which is meant to find the sys_call_table of the computer, and change some values.

However, when I try to compile it, i get the following message:

```
WARNING: "set_memory_rw" [/home/steelslayer/Synergy/synergy-networking/
hook/hook.ko] undefined!
```

Seems weird, as `set_memory_rw` is found in `/asm/cacheflush.h`, which I have included.

Anyway, if I try to ignore and install the module, I get this error message:

```
ERROR: could not insert module hook.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

which is to be expected, from the previous error

dmesg:

```
hook: Unknown symbol set_memory_rw (err 0)
```

Makefile:

```
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=n
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL=n
obj-m += hook.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Includes and defines:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/cacheflush.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>    // loops_per_jiffy

#define CR0_WP 0x00010000   // Write Protect Bit (CR0:16)
/* Just so we do not taint the kernel */
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Relevant code:

```
ret = set_memory_rw(PAGE_ALIGN(addr) - PAGE_SIZE, 3);
```

I really have no idea why this is happening, would love your help.

Comment: Maybe [THIS](https://github.com/jpoimboe/kpatch/commit/b2de4ba059df0a3d09d6148ef0c2292211699945) could help.

Comment: You are the KING!! It works great now. I think I understood what that fix does, but could you explain briefly just in case I got it wrong?

Comment: Simply `set_memory_rw` is not longer exported by recent kernels. That patch fix the problem using` kallsyms_lookup_name` and set function pointers in `kpatch_init`.

Comment: Great! quick question, how does `kallsyms_lookup_name` finds the function if it is not exported?

Comment: Take a look [HERE](https://onebitbug.me/2011/03/04/introducing-linux-kernel-symbols/)